# Python Discord Bot Commands Decorator within classes

Tags: python, discord

Hey I was coding a discord bot, however I can't figure out how to write the commands decorator, I think that's because I am putting all the code in a class, without a class the commands work fine since I can use the a variable that has been initialized to the bot, but I can't use `self` here. However how can I add a command within a class.

Right now it keeps throwing a command not found error, I know I can use cogs but I am just wondering a way to do it within the class currently.

```
import discord
from extensions import data, database
from discord.ext import commands

async def get_prefix(ctx, message):

    # Fetches the prefixes for the guild from the database
    return data.select(guild_id=message.guild.id, extract='prefixes',)

class DeveloperBot(commands.Bot,):

    async def on_ready(self):

        print ('Discord Developer Bot is running; {0.user}'.format(self))

        await commands.Bot.change_presence(
                                            self,
                                            status=discord.Status.idle,
                                            activity=discord.Game('Playing Rockets')
                                            )

        # Checks if the Database file exists
        database.check_guild()

    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        
        data.update(guild_id=guild.id, guild_name=guild.name)

    async def on_guild_leave(self, guild):

        data.remove(guild_id=guild.id)

    # problem is here
    commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx, message):
        
        await ctx.send('Hello')

bot = DeveloperBot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
bot.run('token')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `@commands.command()`. The `@` signifies the *syntactic sugar* for a decorator.

*PS*: You also have redundant commas like, `commands.Bot,` and `extract='prefixes',`. Also, adding those lines in between function signatures and the actual function code makes the code a bit less readable. In addition, for the bot presence change, do:

```py
await commands.Bot.change_presence(
    status=discord.Status.idle,
    activity=discord.Game('Playing Rockets')
)
```

Passing `self` is redundant as it is passed by Python implicitly.